# Programatically setting the user and password for authentication. How to avoid the security question?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, popupwindow

I'm developing an application for a Hotel where the costumers capture some snapshots and then upload them to their facebook.

Using the graph API it makes you identify yourself on facebook using the security question or identifying your friends.

I want to be able to identify the clients on facebook without the need of pop ups, specifying the user and password that they have previously given me

Is that possible?

If not, if I use the same computer to connect a lot of different people onto facebook, I get asked all the security questions. Can this be avoided with a digital certificate or anything like that?

**Edited to add back info that was in an answer**

The user 'Authorise my app' already. It's part of the facebook login process.

This should be right way:

1. The user captures a photo with the webcam.
2. The user introduces the email and password IN MY OWN FORM
3. I connect to facebook through my application, submitting the email & password and write some nice text in the user's wall.

This is what i'm doing now:

1. The user captures a photo with the webcam.
2. I connect to facebook using my desktop app. A facebook login window appears.
3. Sometimes, facebook indicates that this computer is login too much accounts, and ask for an aditional security ( phrase or friend's name).
4. The user grant access to my application.
5. My application write some nice text in the user's wall.

I need that the user write its own email & password in my form, because there is no keyboard ( it's a touch screen system) And if i show the Windows Touch Screen Window, there is some 'dangerous' keys like 'window' that i do not wan

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean, I'm pretty sure taking the user's facebook login, password and security answers is breaking quite a few of the Facebook T+Cs and privacy policies.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do instead is have the user "Authorise your app" this way your application will be given an AccessToken which can then be used to perform the activities you need.

Look into the OAuth protocol and the Graph API

Start here:

http://oauth.net/2/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=616612017